# Printf formatting a variable without forking?

Tags: printf, zsh

For my powerlevel10k custom prompt, I currently have this function to display the seconds since the epoch, comma separated. I display it under the current time so I always have a cue to remember roughly what the current epoch time is.

```
function prompt_epoch() {
  MYEPOCH=$(/bin/date +%s | sed ':a;s/\B[0-9]\{3\}\>/,&/;ta')
  p10k segment -f 66 -t ${MYEPOCH}
}
```

My prompt looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMpmw.jpg

I've been told I can do this without the forked processes using these commands:

```
$ zmodload -F zsh/datetime p:EPOCHSECONDS
$ printf "%'d" $EPOCHSECONDS
1,648,943,504
```

But I'm not sure how to do that without the forking. I know to add the `zmodload` line in my `~/.zshrc` before my powerlevel10k is sourced, but formatting `${EPOCHSECONDS}` isn't something I know how to do without a fork.

If I were doing it the way I know, this is what I'd do:

```
function prompt_epoch() {
  MYEPOCH=$(printf "%'d" ${EPOCHSECONDS})
  p10k segment -f 66 -t ${MYEPOCH}
}
```

But as far as I understand it, that's still forking a process every time the prompt is called, correct? Am I misunderstanding the advice given because I don't think I can see a way to get the latest epoch seconds without running some sort of process, which requires a fork, correct?

Answer (score 2):

The `printf` zsh builtin can assign the value to a variable using the `-v` flag. Therefore my function can be rewritten as:

```sh
function prompt_epoch() {                                                                                       
  printf -v MYEPOCH "%'d" ${EPOCHSECONDS}                                      
  p10k segment -f 66 -t ${MYEPOCH}                                             
}
```

Thanks to this answer in Unix Stackoverflow: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/697807/101884